# Create column that is equal to the value of an existing column in same file +1?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a tab delimited text file with several million rows and with 2 columns that looks like this:

```
1 693731
1 729679
1 730087
1 731718
1 734349
```

I want to add an additional column to the file that is equal to the value of column 2 + 1. So for the above example it would look like this:

```
1 693731 693732
1 729679 729680
1 730087 730088
1 731718 731719
1 734349 734350
```

What would be the best way to do this using unix shell? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're dealing with columnar data, "awk" is a good tool. It also has math capabilities built-in, so it's a natural for this:

```
awk '{ print $1"\t"$2"\t"($2+1); }' < data.tsv
```

`awk` runs this code for every line in the input. For each of those lines, the `$` notation indicates a column: `$1` is the first column in the current row, `$2` is the second, and so on.

Though I prefer explicit column enumeration, you may use ghoti's optimization, where `$0` represents all data on the current row:

```
awk '{ print $0"\t"($2+1); }' < data.tsv
```

Because of the UNIX toolbox approach, there are many ways to solve this problem. Whether or not this is "best" depends on many factors: speed, maintainability, portability, etc.

Comment: Or even `awk '{ print $0,$2+1 }'`, but unfortunately the question is off-topic, as it's asking for a recommended tool rather than a fix to the OP's code.